# How make android pairing request dialog for stay untill user enter the paring key and press ok?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

In android phone , try to pair with some other device( BTLE device) via android App , But in android phone pairing request dialog not waiting for until user enter the passkey. It closed automatically. Please help me to resolve the problem.

Comment: I think that there is a problem with your code. It should not close automatically

Comment: Thanks for your comments . this behavior not consistent always. Some time it waits for user input.